# set the selected text visible in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

```
1 Programmatically inserting text into a text box
2 Setting the caret to the end.
3 Making the caret visible (i.e. scroll the text box content)
4 Select some of the text from last programmatically,
5 **set the selected text visible.** (i.e. scroll the text box content)
```

I can do 1,2,3,4. but i am unable to do 5.This problem exist only in IE9+

any solution??

Comment: provide the code you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

setSelectionRange() does not completely support with IE.

so after googling a lot I replaced it with below code and it worked for me.

```
function setSelection(field, start, charsTobeSelected) {
    end = start + charsTobeSelected;
    if (field.createTextRange) {
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
        field.focus();
    } else if (field.setSelectionRange) {
        field.focus();
        field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if (typeof field.selectionStart != 'undefined') {
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
        field.focus();
    }
}
```